# Setting the previous gridview data of unbound data fields

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am stuck again! I am making a sales application where I am fetching the items from the database by selecting a few checkboxes. There is a button which I click after selecting certain checkboxes and the items are fetched in a gridview. I have 2 unbound fields- "Quantity"(having dropdowns) and "Amount"(as a label). I select the quantity and the amount is computed in the "Amount" column. I also compute the total of the "Amount" column perfectly.

The problem starts when I uncheck a check box or want to delete a certain item, the postback event fires and that item is deleted or that row but side by side the earlier selected values from the dropdowns and the amount labels are also reversed- i mean the previous values are lost as it takes it as a completely new query.

Is there any way to save the previous values no matter I delete or add new items in the grid....?? Please HELP!

The aspx is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" 
        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="true">
          <footerstyle backcolor="LightCyan"
      forecolor="MediumBlue"/>
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="item_ID" HeaderText="ID" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
        <ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuantity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlQuantity_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="purchase_price">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" Text='<%#Eval("purchase_price") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
        <ItemTemplate>                        
            <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" Text='<%#Eval("purchase_price") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

And here is the CodeBehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

    }

    else
    {
        //this is where I am stuck I think so....

        //GridViewRow gvr = ((DropDownList)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        //for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    var ddlQuantity = gvr.FindControl("ddlQuantity") as DropDownList;
        //    Label2.Text = ddlQuantity.SelectedValue.ToString();

       //}
    }

}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        List<String> wheres = new List<String>();

        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            wheres.Add("'pepsi'");
        }

        if (CheckBox2.Checked)
        {
            wheres.Add("'coke'");
        }

        if (CheckBox3.Checked)
        {
            wheres.Add("'juice'");
        }
        String whereclause = String.Join(",", wheres.ToArray());



        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxx; Initial Catalog=xxx; Integrated Security=True";
        conn.Open();
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from item_purchase where item_name in ("+whereclause+")", conn);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select item_purchase.purchase_date,item_purchase.purchase_price,item_purchase.item_ID,items.item_name from item_purchase inner join items on items.item_ID = item_purchase.item_ID where items.item_name in (" + whereclause + ") ", conn);

        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_names", whereclause);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();

        ViewState["currentTable"] = ds;


    }

}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlQuantity") as DropDownList;
        if (ddl != null)
        {
            ddl.DataSource = new List<string>() { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
            ddl.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void ddlQuantity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int quantity;
    GridViewRow gvr = ((DropDownList)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    var ddlQuantity = gvr.FindControl("ddlQuantity") as DropDownList;
    var lblAmount = gvr.FindControl("lblAmount") as Label;
    var lblPrice = gvr.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label;
    int.TryParse(ddlQuantity.SelectedValue, out quantity);
    //Label1.Text = quantity.ToString();

    int pr = int.Parse(lblPrice.Text);
    int qt = int.Parse(ddlQuantity.SelectedValue);

    //Label2.Text += (pr*qt).ToString();


    lblAmount.Text = (pr * qt).ToString();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        gvr = GridView1.Rows[i] as GridViewRow;
        var lblrowamnt = gvr.FindControl("lblAmount") as Label;
        sum += int.Parse(lblrowamnt.Text);
    }
    Label2.Text = sum.ToString();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid all asp.net server controls (except for page) in web form development as well as postback. Of course, I recommend doing the same.

At any rate, your interested in the concept of *[ASP.NET State Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100).aspx):*

---

You'll probably be particularly interested in:

***Application Reference***: [HttpApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate(v=vs.100).aspx)

***Session Reference***: (inproc) HttpSessionState objects : [ASP.NET Session Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx)

***Cookie Reference***: 'Session' cookies : [ASP.NET Cookies Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx)

---

The [System.Web.UI.Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) Class itself (which you are likely inheriting in your code behind page) has inherited properties that expose these instances already..

**Application Method Code Sample**

```
this.Application("SomeObject") = SomeObject;
SomeType SomeObject = (SomeType)this.Application("SomeObject");
```

**Session Method Code Sample**

```
this.Session("SomeObject") = SomeObject;    
SomeType SomeObject = (SomeType)this.Session("SomeObject");
```

**Cookie Method Code Sample**

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("SomeSettingValue");    
aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();    
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);    
this.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```